# Parse files within folder - move to .xls

Tags: bash, shell, powershell

I'm still learning how to script so excuse my rookie question.

Let's say I have a folder, ie: "FolderTest" that contains multiple .txt files formatted as: AAA_BBB_CC. I want to take ALL of these files within the folder & move them into 1 excel sheet delimited by "_" so that the excel sheet would have:

AAA    BBB    CC

AAA    BBB    CC
...

Tabbed/separated.

I understand how to do this file name by file name, but how do I do this for a whole folder?

The code I have for an individual file is:
Cat FILENAME | tr ‘_’ ‘\t’ > parsed.xls

Thanks

Comment: I advise you to put these in a CSV rather than an Excel spreadsheet. It's MUCH easier that way. Do you mean you want to read each of the files and put their contents into an Excel spreadsheet?  I don't understand your example output.

Comment: if you are using powershell then I would have a look at Get-ChildItem path/to/dir -File.  That will give you every file inside the specified directory. I strongly advise you to do as adbertram says but if you want exactly what you've written then: $items = Get-ChildItem /path/to/Dir -File; $items.Name -join "_" with give you AAA_BBB_CCC

Comment: @heres, you're almost there. To get *all* the files, you want `cat *.txt | tr ...`